# How many US airports have 4 or more parallel runways?

Tags: usa, runways, parallel-runways

Which airports in the US have four or more parallel runways?

How many are planning additions in the next 5 years?

A few years back, 10 years, Charlotte opened their 3rd parallel runway and it was said to be only one in seven in the country. Just wondered if there is an updated number for 4+ runways. I have searched and some sites have great information but I am not sure it is up to date. Not trying to offput just looking for information that might not be posted to the public.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [Aviation.se]! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], especially on [what makes a good question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Knowing this info will help us help you better.

Comment: @WilNeumann: I think it will help if you narrow down your definition of "parallel runway". If you look at [Bianfable's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/68019/3721), for example, it includes KDFW (Dallas/Fort Worth International Airport) with runways 13L/31R and 17L/35R which in my opinion are not really "parallel" and runways 13L/31R and 13R/31L which while meeting the mathematical definition of "parallel", are actually on opposite ends of the airport and so don't meet the colloquial interpretation of "parallel" which implies proximity.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Runways 13L/31R and 17L/35R at KDFW are not parallel and have never been counted as parallel runways. I simply listed all runways the airport has (now updated for more clarity).

Comment: That would seem surprising for CLT to be only one of 7 with 3 or more parallels. Even BNA has 3 parallels and has for as long as I can remember (certainly much farther back than 10 years.) ATL and ORD have 5.

Comment: @JörgWMittag At least in the U.S., 'parallel runways' doesn't not imply proximity, other than that they are at the same airport. It just means the number of runways at that airport that are parallel to each other and, thus, can be used for simultaneous flight operations. For example, ATL has 5 parallel runways, so it can do 3 arrivals and 2 departures (or 2 arrivals and 3 departures) at the same time without interference. The runways are spread out enough laterally that they don't interfere with each other's operations. Within a pair, one is used for takeoff and the other for landing.

Answer (score 18):

Based on my current navigation database (AIRAC 1909, valid from 2019-08-15), I found 7 US airports with 4 (or more) parallel runways:

- **KATL** ([Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartsfield%E2%80%93Jackson_Atlanta_International_Airport)):
  5 parallel runways: 08L/26R, 08R/26L, 09L/27R, 09R/27L, 10/28
- **KDEN** ([Denver International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver_International_Airport)):
  4 parallel runways: 16L/34R, 16R/34L, 17L/35R, 17R/35L
  and 2 more parallel runways: 07/25, 08/26
- **KDFW** ([Dallas/Fort Worth International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas/Fort_Worth_International_Airport)):
  5 parallel runways: 17L/35R, 17C/35C, 17R/35L, 18L/36R, 18R/36L
  and 2 more parallel runways: 13L/31R, 13R/31L
- **KDTW** ([Detroit Metropolitan Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Metropolitan_Airport)):
  4 parallel runways: 03L/21R, 03R/21L, 04L/22R, 04R/22L
  and 2 more parallel runways: 09L/27R, 09R/27L
- **KLAX** ([Los Angeles International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_International_Airport)):
  4 parallel runways: 06L/24R, 06R/24L, 07L/25R, 07R/25L
- **KMCO** ([Orlando International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_International_Airport)):
  4 parallel runways: 17L/35R, 17R/35L, 18L/36R, 18R/36L
- **KORD** (Chicago [O'Hare International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Hare_International_Airport)):
  5 parallel runways: 09L/27R, 09R/27L, 10L/28R, 10C/28C, 10R/28L
  and 2 more parallel runways: 04L/22R, 04R/22L

I do not know how many are planning additions, but I linked the Wikipedia article for each of the airports, maybe that will help you find more information on that.

**Trivia**: There are only 3 airports outside the US with 4 parallel runways: **LFPG** (Paris [Charles de Gaulle Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle_Airport)), **LFTM** ([Istanbul Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Airport)) and **ZSPD** ([Shanghai Pudong International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_Pudong_International_Airport)).

Comment: The Wikipedia article for O'Hore says they are currently working on adding a sixth parallel runway, bringing the total to 6+2...

Comment: Fairbanks International Airport (PAFA) lists 4 parallel runways. 2L/20R, 2R/20L, 2W/20W, and 2/20.  The catch is 2W/20W is a water runway for float planes and 2/20 is a dirt/gravel runway used for ski planes.

Comment: @Gerry nice catch! My database does not include the water runway, that's why it did not show up.

Comment: ATL is indeed the world's biggest (busiest?  something) airport, so it makes sense it's in the list, I guess.

Comment: @Fattie It is indeed, by [passenger numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_airports_by_passenger_traffic). ATL had 107 milliion passengers in 2018. Interestingly, Europe's busiest airport (London Heathrow) with 80 million passengers only has 2 runways!

Comment: thanks for that!  @Bianfable  ATL is surely the best of the very large airports, IMO

Comment: @Bianfable US airports have abnormally low average seats per aircraft due to all the regional airlines, so they need more runways to move the same number of people.